# Attribute Set Name

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Hello Stackexchange Team,

I would like to have the attribute name "Letop" near by short description...
as u can see it in this foto. where u see  "**1 Letop**" i would like to move this position to "**1 Op Vooraard**"

i would like to know, where do i have to go to change the position.

thanks,
Ralfe

[image: Product d description]

[image: short information]

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your template and is not configured usualy from admin. But you can easily print it by doing following:

1. Find out where is the phtml file that that prints short description. (You can do it by from admin stores/configuration/[advanced]developer switch template hints on)

   2. After the line something like `$product->getData('short_description')` or `$product->getShortDescription()`
      Add `$product->getLetop()`.

Comment: i can't find nothing with this attribute code...

Comment: It is not there yet. Add the line to the template and you will see it is printed.

Comment: this is the only code which i found in -> /home/public_html/amboim.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

<caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('More Information') ?></caption>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>

Comment: This does not seem to be right peace of cofe. If you emty the file for a second delete it - short_description disappears? (disable the cache first)

Comment: Hi, thanks to answer all my questions
May i give u the access to my computer, so that u can do it for me?
of maybe the name of the link of the site, so that u can see it?

Thanks